# Como selecionar um trecho do texto em uma String?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Estou criando um arquivo de texto e usando alguns delimitadores (`<#` e `#>`) preciso selecionar o que está dentro do delimitador `<# texto.delimitado #>`. Usando a função `split()` do JavaScript.

Qual seria a melhor expressão regular para isso? Já usei a Expressão Regular (`<#|#>`), mas não trouxe o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Com essa expressão

```js
/<#(.*?)#>/
```

Você pode capturar o texto entre `<#` e `#>`.

Para obter todos os *match* você precisa utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```js
// cria um objeto RegExp com a flag global
var regex = new RegExp("<#(.*?)#>", "g");

var teste = "<# Meu primeiro teste aqui é # bem esperto #> "
            + "<# Este é meu # segundo # teste #>";
```

E para executar o regex:

```js
var match;
while ((match = regex.exec(teste))) // se chegou ao fim retorna null
{
    console.log(match[1]); // match[1] = o que está entre parenteses
}
```

Resultado:

```
Meu primeiro teste aqui é # bem esperto
Este é meu # segundo # teste
```

Comment: +1 pela simplicidade no código e na explicação.

Answer (score 12):

**Podemos** usar sua expressão regular `<#|#>` *sem* problemas. Assim, utilizando o método `split()`, conforme pedido, pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
/* Declarações gerais */
var er = new RegExp("<#|#>","g");
var dados_arquivo = new String("<#texto.delimitado.1#><#texto.delimitado.2#>");
var i = new Number();
var resultado = new Array();

/* Obtém os dados que importam */
resultado = dados_arquivo.split(er);

/* Remove os itens não desejados (criados pelo método split) */
for(i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++)
{   
    if(resultado[i] == "")
    {
        resultado.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

**O resultado** é uma *array* (vetor) com os valores "*texto.delimitado.1*" e "*texto.delimitado.2*".

**Na parte final do código**, existe um `for` que serve para remover itens vazios da *array* criados pelo split. Explicando:

O `split()` pega tudo o que "casa" (*match*) e joga fora e, o que não "casa", ele retorna como um *array*. **Porém**, como o split pega tudo à esquerda e direita do que "casou" (mas que não foi casado), onde não há nada ele simplesmente pega este "nada" e coloca como mais um item da *array* resultante.

**Vale notar que** o caso de existir texto que não esteja entre "*<#*" e "*#>*" (nesta ordem): a parcela de texto que não esteja entre "*<#*" e "*#>*" é vista como fronteiriça deles (como explicado anteriormente), mesmo que não esteja entre os delimitadores em si. Isso pois a ER utilizada não enxerga estes delimitadores como uma unidade, mas sim como dois separadores distintos pois estão separados por "*ou*" (|). Exemplo:

- altere o código acima com

  ```
  var dados = new String("a<#texto.delimitado.1#>b<#texto.delimitado.2#>c");
  ```
- o resultado final será 5 itens: "a", "texto.delimitado.1", "b", "texto.delimitado.2" e "c"

**Assim**, é importante que, se isso ocorrer, utilize-se de um algoritmo que remova *primeiro* estes textos indesejados dos dados. Se este for o caso, pode utilizar o código abaixo:

```
/* Declarações gerais */
var er = new RegExp("<#|#>","g");
var dados_arquivo = new String("a<#texto.delimitado.1#>b<#texto.delimitado.2#>c");
var i = new Number();
var resultado = new Array();

/* Algorítimo auxiliar // INÍCIO */
var er_auxiliar = new RegExp("<#.*?#>","g");
var texto_delimitado = dados_arquivo.match(er_auxiliar);

while(texto_delimitado.length > 1)
{   
    texto_delimitado[0] = texto_delimitado[0] + texto_delimitado[1];
    texto_delimitado.splice(1,1);
}
/* Algoritmo auxiliar // FIM */

/* Obtém dados que importam */
resultado = texto_delimitado[0].split(er); /* <- Foi trocada a variável */

/* Remove os itens não desejados (criados pelo método split) */
for(i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++)
{       
    if(resultado[i] === "")
    {
        resultado.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

**A novidade** (algoritmo adicionado) foi marcado no código. Foram feitas alterações no nome das variáveis para ficar de acordo com o código novo.

**O que o algoritmo adicionado faz** é o seguinte: ele procura nos dados obtidos do arquivo original (com os delimitadores) e obtém tudo que está entre "*<#*" e "*#>*" (por meio de uma ER auxiliar para o método `match()`. O resultado seria um *array*. Mas o que se tem no `while` é justamente uma forma de unir todo o resultado obtido como se fosse uma única *string* para que o algoritmo (que já se tinha) possa separar tudo com sua ER.

É isso; espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Uma forma mais simples seria usar essa regex para o delimitador `^<#|#>$|#><#`, no primeiro exemplo. Assim não há a necessidade do loop no final e cobre todos os casos. No entanto não sei se é válido assumir que os delimitadores estarão em sequencia sem espaços ou quebras de linha.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal essa expressão regular, `^<#|#>$|#><#^`, _'não funciona'_ em ambos os exemplos: 

a) ela só permite remover os "" (vazios) internos dos algoritmos, deixando os "" laterais ficarem na _array_ final (exemplo: `,texto.delimitado.1,texto.delimitado.2,`).

b) assumindo que não tenha somente texto delimitado por "_<#_" e "_#>_", este texto estaria na _array_ final (primeiro exemplo). Mas o próprio algoritmo que adicionei no segundo exemplo, para um caso desses, já corrige.

Não consegui enxergar a não necessidade do _loop_ (`for`ou `while` em ambos os casos). Pode explicitar melhor?

Comment: De fato, eu não levei em consideração os itens no início e no final da array, você está certo. Também assumi que não haveria itens fora dos delimitadores.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma usando `filter` e `map`:

```js
var string = "bla bla <# texto.delimitado #> bla bla bla<# texto.delimitado2#>";
var resultado = string.split(/<#/).filter(function(v){
   return ~v.indexOf("#>");
}).map(function(v){
   return v.match(/(.*)#>/)[1].trim();
})
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Tive dificuldade em acompanhar a expressão no filtro. Esse `~v.indexOf`, é para garantir que, caso seja `-1`, negue todos os bits e se torne falso?

Comment: Cara, eu uso como uma forma curta de `indexOf() != -1`

Comment: entendi agora. Isso parece código de code-golf, bem mínimo. Não estou nem um pouco acostumado com isso. Obrigado por esclarecer =D

Answer (score 0):

De uma forma mais simples

```
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var texto = '[Palavra chave 1 = 296] Se refere ao item do produto para direcionamento. [Palavra chave 2 = 1234]'
alert(texto.match(regex));
```