# Regex que capture data informada por usuario, digitada em uma frase

Tags: javascript, regex

Se eu tenho uma frase: `"melhor 01/01/2016 - 05/01/2016"`
Como eu posso recuperar as datas dessa frase usando regex?
 assim: `var data1="01/01/2016" , data2="05/01/2016"`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como selecionar um trecho do texto em uma String?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450/como-selecionar-um-trecho-do-texto-em-uma-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dá para fazer isso utilizando o método `String.match`. Você precisa passar uma expressão regular que, ao ser avaliada, retornará um `array` contendos os valores que bateram com a expressão passada.

Exemplo:

```js
var regex_date = /(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d{1}|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[1-2])\/\d{4}/g

var dates = 'Vamos sair em 04/02/2015 e voltar em 04/05/2015'.match(regex_date)

for (date in dates) {
  document.write(dates[date] + "<br>")

}
```

Comment: Também pode ser feito com o método `exec` do Regex: `regex_date.exec(texto)`. O resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Interessante @PedroCamaraJunior, adicione sua resposta. Pois é até melhor, pois ao invés de chamar na string, ele pode simplesmente reutilizar a regex

Comment: Acho que fica melhor como um complemento para a sua. Referência: [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!

Comment: Testei aqui @PedroCamaraJunior, não funcionou da mesma forma que meu exemplo. Ia colocar a referência, mas ia dar informação errada

Comment: Acho que é o teu `Regex`, ele está agrupando errado (Não sei exatamente onde, não sou muito bom com regex). Usei esse `/([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-9]{4})/` pra testar e nos dois casos trás o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior ah, mas aí você mudou a regex. No meu caso, a primeira funcionou, tanto que tem no exemplo

Comment: Sim. Depois posto uma nova resposta então. :)